# Where is my test helper for ember-power-select?

Tags: ember.js

I am reading the docs for `ember-power-select` testings [here](http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/test-helpers).

On the setup, it says:

```
import registerPowerSelectHelpers from '../../tests/helpers/ember-power-select';

registerPowerSelectHelpers();
...
```

I do not see `ember-power-select` in my `tests/helpers/` directory. Am I supposed to install it separately, or was it supposed to come by default?

I installed `ember-power-select` by running the command suggested: `ember install ember-power-select`.

How can I use some of the `power-select helpers` like `selectChoose()`, `selectSearch()`, &c. like prescribed on the docs?

Comment: The [test-support folder is merged into the consuming application's test folder](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#developing-addons-and-blueprints). If the addon is installed, you're good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#addon-project-structure) explanation about addons; there says "test-support/ - merged with the application’s tests/" and if you look at [source code](https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select/tree/master/test-support) of ember-power-select there is a `helper` directory under `test-support` directory. This means when you install ember-power-select; this directory behaves like it is merged with your application's tests directory. It does not matter whether you see the `tests/helpers/ember-power-select.js` under your project. You can access it like this. Let's assume your project is named `sample-project`; then you can just import relevant function as follows:

```
import registerPowerSelectHelpers from 'sample-project/tests/helpers/ember-power-select';
```

from within your `acceptance-test` and call it before your test begin `registerPowerSelectHelpers();` and you are able to use `selectChoose()`, `selectSearch()` as you wish.

Similarly you can just import integration test helpers as follows:

```
import { typeInSearch, clickTrigger } from 'sample-project/tests/helpers/ember-power-select'
```